# ScrollView is only showing single view inside its sub-hierarchy

Tags: android, android-xml, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am supposed to add a `ScrollView`, to enable user to scroll down after the button. However, it is not showing what it supposed to show.

Whatever I add after the `Button`, doesn't show up on device/emulator. I am supposed to add `ImageView` under the `Button` , but it seem to not displaying anything after the `Button`.

Following is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">   
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Restaurant Location:"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />    
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: By "it is not showing what it supposed to show", do you mean nothing shows up?

Comment: nothing shows up after the button, i am suppose to add imageView under the button, but it seem to not displaying anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not aligning the views correctly. For example, there's no `editText2`, `editText` and `imageView3` and you're aligning your views around left or below of them.

Either replace `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` or use this XML (I've replaced those unknown IDs with correct ones):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">   
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Restaurant Location:"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView14" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView15"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```